# release swap if enough RAM available in linux

Tags: linux, swap, ram

i have just released my swap with these commands

```
$ swapoff -av
```

Waited few seconds then

```
$ swapon -av
```

It worked like a charm, it can be named a good practice?

I assume its only posible if i have enough free or cache-used RAM. Am I wrong?

Comment: What's the point of this? (And how is it programming-related?)

Comment: It's always possible, but it's a stupid thing to do. It does not buy you anything, and if you don't have enough physical RAM, the OOM killer kills random processes until it can satisfy the page requests...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's good you care but it's a better to just drop the cache:

```
sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Answer (score 1):

That should work only if the combined memory requirements of all processes fit into your RAM. So I don't believe it is really good practice, but YMMV.

Actually, swap is currently so slow that it does not matter that much. Because accessing a kilobyte on disk (many milliseconds) is more than 100000 times slower than accessing a kilobyte in RAM (fraction of microseconds). Back in the early 1990s the ratio was not that big, and at that time it made sense to have processes with a working set slightly bigger than RAM. It has much less sense today (and RAM price is cheap, and RAM size is very big).

Of course, cold data of nearly idle processes is still swapped out (in particular to increase the file system cache).

Today's swap space is also used for hibernation purposes.